# The maximum value of the smaller root of given quadratic function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, maxima-minima

> Consider the quadratic expression :
> $$ f(x) = x^2 +(a+2)x + (a^2 - a +2 ) $$ given is that $a , p, q , (p<q)$ are real numbers and p and q are the roots of the equation $f(x)=0$.
> Q1) find the maximum value of q.
> Q2) find the maximum value of p.

**Solution** Q1) since q is a root of f(x), we have $f(q) = 0$. This gives:
$$ q^2 + (a+2)q + a^2 - a + 2  = 0 $$
Writing this as a quadratic in a we have
$$ a^2 + (q-1)a + q^2 +2q +2  = 0 $$
Since a is given to be real this quadratic must have its determinant greater than or equal to zero, which gives:
$$ (q-1)^2 -4(1)(q^2 +2q +2) \ge 0 $$
Which gives:
$$ -3q^2 -10q -7 \ge 0 $$
which gives: $q \in [-7/3 , -1]$ giving the maximum value of $q$ (the larger root ) to be -1.
I am however stuck with how to go about formulating the maximum value of the smaller root.

Comment: I have a concern: $a$ is a fixed real number and when you wrote $a^2+(q-1)a+q^2+2q+2 = 0$ and consider this as quadratic and said since it have two solutions then ... This is not correct take $a=2$ for example! check does your argument make sense?

Comment: I have an issue if $a$ is fixed and you determined the maximum value for $q$ then $p$ is determined already cant vary because then $$x^2+(a+2)x+a^2-a+2=(x-p)(x-q)$$ $a+2 = -p-q$

Comment: I think that the answer for Q2 is that there is no maximum. Since $p\lt q$, we have $\frac 23\color{red}{\lt} a\color{red}{\lt} 2$ for which there is no maximum $p=\frac{-a-2-\sqrt{-3a^2+8a-4}}{2}$.

Comment: @Mamta Kumari : If you don't have any typo in the question, then the answer for Q2 is that there is no maximum (see my comment above). If $p\color{red}{\le} q$ instead of $p\lt q$, then the answer for Q2 is $-\frac 43$ for $a=\frac 23$.

Comment: @user2661923 : The **smaller** root $p=\frac{-a-2\color{red}-\sqrt{-3a^2+8a-4}}{2}$ has no maximum for $\frac 23\lt a\lt 2$.

Comment: @mathlove It just hit me - you are right.  It took me a while to wrap my brain around this.  I will post an addendum in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to mathlove's comments to the original query which indicated that I had misinterpreted the problem.  The answer has been corrected.

I upvoted the original query, for the very good work.  However, I prefer the
approach of solving for
$p$ and $q$, given **any** fixed value of $a$, and then
analyzing further.

$\{p,q\} = \frac{1}{2} \times 
[-(a +2) \pm \sqrt{(a+2)^2 - 4(a^2 - a + 2)}]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
[-(a +2) \pm \sqrt{(a^2 + 4a + 4) - 4(a^2 - a + 2)}]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
[-(a +2) \pm \sqrt{(-3)a^2 + 8a - 4)}].$

Since $p,q$ are required to be real, with $p < q$, it is required that
$h(a) = [(-3)a^2 + 8a - 4)]$ must be **positive**. 
That is, if $h(a) = 0$, this would cause $p = q$, which is forbidden by the premise to the problem.

Solving for $h(a) = 0$ gives
$a = \frac{1}{-6} [-8 \pm \sqrt{64 - 48}] $ 
$= \frac{1}{-6} [-8 \pm \sqrt{16}] $ 
$= \frac{1}{-3} [-4 \pm 2] $

This means that $a$ must be in the **open interval**
$(\frac{2}{3}, 2).$

**Note** : It is possible that **different** values for $a$ **might** be used
to maximize the values for $q$ and $p$.

For $a$ in the range, $(\frac{2}{3}, 2).$ 
The **larger** root and the **smaller** root must be *separately* maximized.
What needs to be maximized are the two values of 
$g(a) = [-(a +2) \pm \sqrt{(-3)a^2 + 8a - 4)}]$.

Unfortunately, I was never taught any **pre-calculus** method for
maximizing the two roots of $g(a)$. In terms of calculus, we have that 
$\displaystyle g'(a) = -1 \pm 
\left[\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{-6a + 8}{\sqrt{(-3)a^2 + 8a - 4)}}\right].$

I must find all values of $a$ such that $g'(a) = 0.$

In order to do this, I must solve 
$(-1) \times \sqrt{(-3)a^2 + 8a - 4} \pm 
\left[\frac{1}{2} \times (-6a + 8)\right] = 0.$

This means that $(4) \times [(-3)a^2 + 8a - 4)]$ must = $(-6a + 8)^2.$

This means that $(-12a^2 + 32a - 16)]$ must = $(36a^2 -96a + 64).$

This means that $0 = (48a^2 -128a + 80).$

This means that $0 = (3a^2 -8a + 5).$

This means that $a = \frac{1}{6} \times \left[ 8 \pm \sqrt{64 - 60}\right].$

This means that $a = \frac{1}{6} \times \left[ 8 \pm 2\right].$

This means that the only values for $a$ that **might** yield $g'(a) = 0$ are 
$a = \frac{10}{6}$ or $a = 1.$

Technically, Calculus would require that I now take the 2nd derivative of $g(a).$

However, that is very messy and fortunately, there is a **shortcut**.

In addition to the **possible** critical points of 
$a = \frac{10}{6}$ or $a = 1$ 
the boundary points of $a = \frac{2}{3}$ and $a = 2$ 
can also be considered.

**However**, when considering the boundary points of $a = \frac{2}{3}$ and $a = 2$,
although $a$ may **approach** one of the boundary points, it can **never** equal either of the boundary points.

This means that I have to calculate the two roots, $p$ and $q$ for each of the
4 values of $a$ above.  Then, I must select the maximum value for the larger root $q$ and the maximum value for the smaller root $p$, when $a$ is restricted to the open interval $(2/3, 2).$

Setting $a = \frac{2}{3}$ yields $\{q,p\}$ of

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-\frac{8}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{-12}{9} + \frac{16}{3} - 4}\right]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-\frac{8}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{-12 + 48 - 36}{9}}\right]$

$ = [-\frac{4}{3} \pm 0].$

In fact, this means that as $a$ approaches 2/3, the smaller root will approach (-4/3) from below and the larger root will approach (-4/3) from above.

.....

Setting $a = 1$ yields $\{q,p\}$ of

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-3 \pm \sqrt{-3  + 8 - 4}\right]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-3 \pm 1\right]$

$ = \{-1, -2\}.$

.....

Setting $a = \frac{5}{3}$ yields $\{q,p\}$ of

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-\frac{11}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{-75}{9} + \frac{40}{3} - 4}\right]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-\frac{11}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{-75 + 120 - 36}{9}}\right]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-\frac{11}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{9}{9}}\right]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-\frac{11}{3} \pm 1\right]$

$ = \{\frac{-4}{3}, \frac{-7}{3}\}.$

.....

Setting $a = 2$ yields $\{q,p\}$ of

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-4 \pm \sqrt{-12  + 16 - 4}\right]$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \times 
\left[-4 \pm 0\right]$

$ = \left[-2 \pm 0\right]$

In fact, this means that as $a$ approaches 2, the smaller root will approach (-2) from below and the larger root will approach (-2) from above.

---

The largest root, $q$ attains the maximum value of $-1$, when $a = 1$.
The smaller root $p$ **approaches** $-4/3$ from below, as $a$ approaches 2/3.

**Addendum**

As mathlove indicated in a comment to the original query, the smaller root $p$ never attains a maximum value in the **open** interval for $a$ of (2/3, 2). I explain this as follows:

First of all, although the boundary points of $a = 2/3$ and $a = 2$ *seem* to be permissible, the original problem specifies the maximum value for $p$, when it is required that $p < q$.  This requirement means that the only permissible values of $a$ are the **open** interval $(2/3, 2)$ rather than the **closed** interval $[2/3,2].$

With respect to the value of $a$, if you examine the 4 pertinent points in my answer, (2/3), 1, (5/3), 2, keeping in mind that the only possible values of $a$ that **might** cause $g'(a) = 0$ are $a=1$ and $a = (5/3)$, you see that :

$E_1:$ 
as $a$ approaches $2/3$ **from above**, the smaller root, $p$, approaches -4/3 **from below**.

$E_2:$ 
In fact, for no value of $a$ in the **open** interval $(2/3, 2)$ does $p$ actually $= -4/3.$

Comment: The maximum or the minimum of $ax^2-bx+c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ should be the vertex of the parabola i.e. the point (-b/(2a) , f(-b/2a)) it is a maximum if $a<0$ and minimum $a>0$

Comment: Obliged to all who contributed, indeed an amazingly written answer.